# Show names who have only one of two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently having the following table:

```
+---------+------------+
| Name    | Number     |
+---------+------------+
|    John |   Supp#10  |
|    John |   1150-20  |
|    Doe  |   1140-09  |
+---------+------------+
```

John has both the Supp#10 and 1150-20 value. Where Doe only has 1140-09 and NOT the Supp%xx value. This Supp# can end in any number.

My requested result is the following

```
+---------+
| Name    |
+---------+
|    Doe  |
+---------+
```

Since Doe does not has any values starting with Supp# but does have a number in the syntax '%-%'

I tried the following

```
select name from t where number like '%-%' and number not like 'Support%'
```

But this isn't working obviously and I can't seem to figure out how I would get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(case when number like 'Supp#%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join and the valid result for both

```
select distinct  name 
from t 
inner join( 
  select  name 
  from t 
  where number not like 'Supp%'
) t2 on t.name =  t2.name
where number like '%-%'
```